# how to make asp.net calendar control to display jewish dates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to change the control so it will display jewish dates.
I have tried the next code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture =
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL");
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
...
}
```

But it just displays the gregorian calendar in hebrew (name of dates).
I got the same result by adding the following to the aspx file:

```
 UICulture="he" Culture="he-IL"
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe you have to set the `culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar` to the `HebrewCalendar`, as kind of displayed in [Two calendar controls with gregorian &amp; arabic dates on single page using asp.net webforms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34507183/215552).

Comment: great, it works!!! thanks!!! can the control display 2 different calendars?